# php __destruct why get different result by file_get_contents

Tags: php, php-7

the content in hint.php is "111"

```
<?php

class T{
    public $filename = "hint.php";

    function __destruct() {
        var_dump(file_get_contents($this->filename));
    }
}

new T();
```

this got

```
string(3) "111"
```

And when I set a variable $t, the result will be different.

```
$t = new T();
```

this got

```
string(0) ""
```

why this happend

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result. Setting `$t = new T();` I still get the contents of my hint.php.

Comment: my php version is PHP Version 7.3.1 system is windows

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40661). It has existed for a long time now and it doesn't look like it will be fixed any time soon.

To avoid this problem don't use relative path in shutdown scripts.